# how to make page wait until delete complete, then refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm pretty new to using javascript, and ajax. So I have a button that's supposed to delete the item when clicked.

```
<button type="submit" class="delete-button" data-id="{{ d_id }}">Delete</button>
```

I used ajax to send the delete POST request. While this is happening (the item takes a while to delete) how can I go about having a loading circle in the HTML. I would like to show a processing bar or something similar while the request is processing and when it's done, refresh the to show the change. Currently after a successful delete, the user can't see the change until they manually refresh the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete-button").click(function () {
        var d_id = $(this).attr('d_id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/delete/" + d_id
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data === 'Deleted') {
                console.log("Deleted") 
            } else {
                console.log("Failed")
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I would use a Boolean to toggle a loading animation and would just call a load function after the delete occurs to refresh the data in place.

Comment: Do you know how to display a modal dialog on the page? Or how to hide/show content while your ajax request is processing?

Comment: @daddygames I have a modal displaying with the buttons. I'm not sure how to show/hide the content

Comment: Showing and hiding content is simple; especially using JQuery. Just $('#content').hide() to hide and $('#content').show() to show. With animation options and such available. My suggestion is that once Delete button is clicked, hide the primary content and display a loader. This can be on the page or in an overlay modal dialog. Then once the ajax "done" method is called, can perform the refresh.